# Reservoir sampling - understanding probabilites

Tags: probability, random

I am reading about reservoir sampling(method for selecting random sample out of some data), but cannot understand a few things about probability I came across.

The article at [blog](http://gregable.com/2007/10/reservoir-sampling.html), says that if I'm picking 1000 elements from a random stream of data the probability of picking 1001 element of the stream is $1000/1001$

Quoting..

> With what probability after the 1001'th step should element 1,001 (or any element for that matter) be in the set of 1,000 elements? The answer is easy: 1,000/1,001.

I'm lost, why is it $1000/1001$? Shouldn't it be $1/1001$, since every element should be equally likely?

Another article [here](http://propersubset.com/2010/04/choosing-random-elements.html), says the same thing in different words..

> The probability of choosing any previous item was 1/N, and with
>   N/(N+1) probability of staying that way. What does this mean?

I think this might be something really basic but I'm not every good at probabilties, and I'm working on it.

Answer (score 1):

You have 1000 elements $x_1,\dots,x_{1000}$ in the list initially. You want to randomly decide whether to add $x_{1001}$ to the list, such that the overall probability of drawing $x_{1001}$ out of the list (taking into account the probability of whether it was added at all) is 1/1001. The probability of drawing $x_{1001}$ after assembling the reservoir will be 1/1000 by definition, so assuming your assembly of the reservoir and your draws from the reservoir are independent, $x_{1001}$ should be added to the reservoir with probability 1000/1001, so that the product of the two probabilities is 1/1001.